# Issue with multiple links from anchor tag - php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Greetings for the day.

I am in the middle of a coupon based website development. As part of it, once the user clicks on the **get coupon** button, I need to display to the user the coupon code as well as redirect them to the merchant website.  To achieve this I am fetching all the details from the database and storing them in php variables, then displaying it in the web page.

```
echo '
                    <div class="col-sm-3 feature" >
                        <div class="panel" id="bar">
                        <div id="propost">
                        <a href="', $LINK, '">
                            <img src="', $IMG, '" class="img-responsive" alt=""/></a>
                            <div class="special-info grid_1 simpleCart_shelfItem">
                                <h5>', $POSTDESC, '</h5>
                                <div id="btnstyle"> </div>  
                                <a href="', $LINK, '" target="_blank" class="', $btn, '" onclick="window.open(', $ccodelink, ');">', $text, '</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div><!-- end panel -->
                    </div><!-- end feature -->';
```

Everything is working as expected apart from the multiple links which I mentioned in the anchor tag. How do I do this?

Comment: Are you getting any `error`?

Comment: What is within `$LINK` Post that too

Comment: @Tushar : Thanks for the reply.  No I am not getting any error, But i could able to open one page which is $link second link which $ccodelink is not getting opened.  Thanks

Comment: @Uchiha : For testing purpose i provided the following values to the variables. $link = http://www.amazon.in/ $ccodelink : http://www.google.in/

Comment: Shouldn't it be `echo '<div>' . $stuff . '</div>'`, points instead of commas?

Comment: Are they comma seperated  values

Comment: @AlexG No problem with the , the problem is i can able to open only one link rather than opening two links specified in the anchor tag

Comment: Tried it with the commas as well, didn't know that works as well. But I find it confusing because youre using "+" in Java and Javascript. I'll stick to a simple point, still it's your choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of different approach using non-obstrusive javascript :

**HTML**

```
<a href="link1" data-secondlink="link2">This is my link</a>
```

**JAVASCRIPT (jQuery)**

```
$('a[data-secondlink]').on('click',function(){
    window.open($(this).data("secondlink'));
});
```

**EXPLANATION**

Unobstrusive javascript is just a best-practice and the many reasons why you should prefer this can easily be found online. The main I would point in this case is that in case requirements change (let's say you need to use a lightbox instead of a new tab/window for example), you just have to update 1 JS file instead of all your PHP/HTML files.

As of the line of code, on click it executes this line, and afterwards it executes the default action of an anchor : requesting the URL in the `href`attribute.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your help.  I modified the code as follows

Comment: Sorry my previous comment is not complete : Modified code as below : <a href="'. $LINK . '" data-secondlink="$ccodelink">', $text, '</a><script>
  $('a[data-secondlink]').on('click',function(){
  window.open($(this).data("secondlink"));
  });
 </script> Now, my code is attempting to open two links which was not happening before.  But instead of redirecting to the value in $ccodelink, it is getting appended to my url ie., mysite/$ccodelink please advise

Comment: To simplify my issue, when i specify static parameter in data-secondlink it is working perfectly fine, where as when i am trying to get that value dynamically from $ccodelink it is not working as expected.

Comment: Hi the issue is resolved now after doing the following modification <a href="'. $LINK . '" data-secondlink="'. $ccodelink . '">', $text, '</a>.  Thanks a lot for your guidance and kind support

Answer (score 1):

You might try this:

```
<a href="url1" onclick="window.open('url2');">Click</a>
```

---

**Updated:**

```
echo '<a href="' . $url1 . '" onclick="window.open(&apos;' . $url2 . '&apos;);">Click</a>';
```

Also: don't put block elements like `div`s into anchors. Thats not valid html :)

Comment: Thanks Alex, when i give static values it is working.  I want to take url1 and url2 values from database, that's the reason i specified $link and $ccodelink variables inside the anchor tag.  Please adviise

Comment: Great answer, I actually understand what the question was now... to navigate somewhere else on your own website and then also open a new tab with a different website.  May I suggest instead of `<?php echo ' <a href="' . $code . '" onclick="window.open("' .$ccodelink. '");">Click</a>';?>` you instead do it in HTML so `<a href="<?php echo $code;?>" onclick="window.open('<?php echo $cccodelink;?>');">Click</a>`

Comment: so I came up with a simple "hack" with `&apos;` if you want to call it like that, updated my post

Comment: Note that inline javascript is bad. Best way to handle this is keep the href attribute but put the other url in a data-attribute and the handle the click event in external script. This will also facilitate maintenance if for some reason the behaviour must be changed (e.g. : lightbox instead of new window, ...)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing concatenating string via ,

replace , with .
in Anchor tag and window.location()

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Even if i replace , with . as suggested still i can go to only one link not two links.